# How do I calculate Pr(model|data) in Bayesian inference with extremely small numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, model, statistics, bayesian

I'm doing Bayesian inference (manually, using a grid search) in Python. I want to calculate the probability of each model given the data. The problem is I can only calculate the 'evidence' in log, otherwise its 0.
So, even though its between 0-1, I can't get the results for:

```
Pr(data|model1) / (Pr(data|model1) + Pr(data|model2))
```

Since each term is 0 in its non-log form.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: give an example with you code and day

Comment: What's your point here? Can't you simply log both sides and calculate `log[p(model|data)]`?

Comment: Also, please do not cross-post. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175301/how-do-i-calculate-prmodel-data-in-bayesian-inference-with-extremely-small-num

Comment: cel  - log[p(model|data)] does not equal log(Pr(data|model1)) / (log(Pr(data|model1)) + log(Pr(data|model2))), which I can calculate.

Comment: @ItayLieder, true. You may want to look up the rules for calculating logarithms first..

Comment: @cel, thank you for engaging my question. Can you please explain your last comment?

Comment: @ItayLieder, you're supposed to calculate `log[p(model|data)]`, what you suggested is to just put a log in front of every term on the right hand side `log(Pr(data|model1)) / (log(Pr(data|model1)) + log(Pr(data|model2)))` and told me that this is not correct. That is true. You are supposed to calculate `log[Pr(data|model1) / (Pr(data|model1) + Pr(data|model2))]`. This can be simplified by logarithm rules. Please look up how you simplify logarithms and do the math yourself. It is not very difficult.

Comment: @cel, I would greatly appreciate it if you can take a few minutes of your time to show me how then.

Comment: @cel, Nevermind, this can actually be proven impossible to be simplified by logarithm rules.

Comment: Sorry, @ItayLieder, I should have calculated this myself. I missed that a sum of two remains and  `numpy.logaddexp` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `logpr1` and `logpr2` be `log(data|model1)` and `log(data|model2)`, respectively, and suppose

```
In [57]: logpr1 = -802

In [58]: logpr2 = -800
```

If you try to express those as probabilities (not logarithms of probabilities), you get 0:

```
In [59]: np.exp(logpr2)
Out[59]: 0.0
```

Now you want to compute

```
log(Pr(data|model1) / (Pr(data|model1) + Pr(data|model2))),
```

which you can also write as

```
log(Pr(data|model1)) - log(Pr(data|model1) + Pr(data|model2)).
```

For the last term, you can use the function [`numpy.logaddexp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html) (which is the essential tip in this answer; see also [`scipy.misc.logsumexp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.logsumexp.html)).  So your calculation is:

```
In [60]: logp = logpr1 - np.logaddexp(logpr1, logpr2)

In [61]: logp
Out[61]: -2.1269280110429918
```

In this case, that number is not very small.  In fact, you can express it as a plain probability:

```
In [62]: np.exp(logp)
Out[62]: 0.11920292202211526
```

Comment: This is what I needed, Thanks Warren!